# How to add timestamp on document create to Firestore from Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing code to set data to Firestore from flutter. What I want is to add a field for the time the data is created, eg "createdOn". DateTime.now() for Flutter takes the time from the device but I would like to get the serverside time. My code is as below:

```
Future updateDataModel(String userName, String userPosition, String userLocation) async{
  return await userCollection.document().setData({
      'userName' : userName,
      'userPosition' : userPosition,
      'userLocation' : userLocation
    });
  }
```

It would be a great help if I could have a field like below that gets the timestamp for firebase.

```
   'createdOn' : TimestampHere,
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

> `serverTimestamp()`: FieldValue Returns a sentinel used with set() or
>   update() to include a server-generated timestamp in the written data.

```
'createdOn':FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

#### References

- [ServerTimestamp](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html)

Comment: The code is asking about flutter, but you're linking to JavaScript documentation.

Comment: Same principle, but linked the flutter one

Comment: How did you defined createdOn field in dart model? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh you can check here https://gist.github.com/TinusJ/b35c6cb4e432b7a92e67e93565318ef3 hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

you can use several types of time stamp ,example date time

```
"timestamp": DateTime.now(),
```

server value

```
'timestamp' : Timestamp.now()
```

Comment: How did you defined createdOn field in dart model? Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firebase,you should store the timestamp from epoch like that

```
DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch
```

Comment: This gives me a weird number (1583957322262781). how can I convert it to readable time?

Comment: Then, just need to use `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(_yourEpochTime)` to re-convert to readable type. The reason why i recommend to use time from epoch is that date time from any when can store the same data. 
It likes `getTime ` method in JavaScript.