# Add a timestamp value from Flutter to Cloud

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a event to my cloud firestore database. However, when I add the event, the date is added as a string whereas in my database, I am using TimeStamp. This is my current code:

```
class _FirstRoute extends State<FirstRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('icons')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data... Please Wait');
            return Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: new Container(
                child: new ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new StreamBuilder(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('tasksDue')
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (!snapshot.hasData)
                            return Text('Loading data... Please Wait');
                          return Container(
                              child: new Row(children: <Widget>[
                                new Expanded(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                  child: new ListView(
                                    children: snapshot.data.documents
                                        .map<Widget>(
                                            (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                      if (document.data()['complete'] != true) {
                                        var now = DateTime.now();
                                          return new Card(
                                              child: new Column(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  new Container(
                                                    
                                          return new Card(
                                              child: new Column(
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  new Container(
                                                    child: new Text(
                                                      document.data()['title'],
                                                      ),
                                                  ),
                                                  new ButtonBar(
                                                    children: <Widget>[
                                                      RaisedButton(
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          _sendToServer(
                                                              document.data()[
                                                                  'title'],
                                                              document.data()[
                                                                  'description'],
                                                              now);
                                                          updateData('tasksDue',
                                                              (document.id), {
                                                            'complete': true
                                                          });
                                                        },
```

So I have set `var now = DateTime.now();` and then called this in `_sendToServer`

```
_sendToServer(title, description, eventDate) {
    var id;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
      CollectionReference reference =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Events');

      await reference.add({
        "title": "$title",
        "description": "$description",
        "id": "$id",
        'event_date': "$eventDate"
      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }
```

When I do this though it adds dateTime as a sting then I get the error `Class 'String' has no instance method 'toDate'.` as I call the value somewhere else with `.toDate()`

I have looked at other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60637087/how-to-add-timestamp-on-document-create-to-firestore-from-flutter) but the solutions didn't work. If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Since you are writing event date as string `"$eventDate"` (wrapped in quotes) writes as string. Write a native date `new Date()` to the database and it will store it as a Firestore Timestamp.

Comment: @Brettski Thank you so much! I hadn't even realised that, I must've just copied and pasted. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the date/timestamp to the database with:

```
'event_date': "$eventDate"
```

Since you enclose `eventData` in `"` marks here, it gets converted to a string.

To pass the raw value of the data:

```
'event_date': DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(eventDate)
```

---

You can also let Firestore [set the timestamp of the server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp), which ensures the vale is affected by any offsets in the user's device time, with:

```
'event_date': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```